# Change the background colour of a mindmap object by using labels

Tags: plantuml

I want to do: change the background colour of all objects with the label `<folder>` to blue

[image]

```
@startmindmap

skinparam backgroundColor transparent

* layer 1
 * layer 2
  * obj
  * obj
  * <&folder> obj folder
 * layer 2
  * <&folder> obj folder
@endmindmap
```

If anyone has experience of this, I would gladly accept any 'pearls of wisdom' they are willing to impart.

Comment: Can you please post the code as well and not just as an image (so people can cut/paste and do some tests).

Comment: I tried your example in the plantuml web server and got a good picture: http://www.plantuml.com/plantuml/uml/SoWkIImgoStCIybDBE3YAixEp2j8B4hCLKXAJCvEByelpKjnpi_9Br8eAKhCAmPAfUQLS75fAUGaLgOMAHXoAS2OHbmAG7P-KXOARQEMbf-Jabfa1n9HWB2HzE1Muv2Qbm9r5G00 Which version of plantuml are you using?

Comment: Thanks for your reminder and I have put the code on it.

Comment: I use [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) as my IDE, and install plugins:PlantUML integration v2.16.0

Comment: Maybe good to open a question at https://forum.plantuml.net/ask or an issue in https://github.com/plantuml/plantuml/issues/new

Comment: Sorry misread initial line, I thought you wrote that you wanted all fields yellow, but you would like to have them as in the image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@startmindmap
skinparam backgroundColor #EEAADD

*[#FF0000] Debian
**[#Orange] Ubuntu
***[#LightGreen] Linux Mint
**[#Green] Rasbian

@endmindmap
```

Using this syntax you can color your boxes.

I found this method on this [link](http://hangaroundtheweb.com/2019/07/mind-maps-in-spacemacs/).

## Demo

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" contentScriptType="application/ecmascript" contentStyleType="text/css" height="130px" preserveAspectRatio="none" style="width:334px;height:130px;background:#EEAADD;" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 334 130" width="334px" zoomAndPan="magnify"><defs><filter height="300%" id="f1n8snf7oca3o3" width="300%" x="-1" y="-1"><feGaussianBlur result="blurOut" stdDeviation="2.0"/><feColorMatrix in="blurOut" result="blurOut2" type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 .4 0"/><feOffset dx="4.0" dy="4.0" in="blurOut2" result="blurOut3"/><feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="blurOut3" mode="normal"/></filter></defs><g><rect fill="#FF0000" filter="url(#f1n8snf7oca3o3)" height="39.9404" rx="12.5" ry="12.5" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="65" x="10" y="49.9702"/><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="14" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" textLength="45" x="20" y="76.8345">Debian</text><rect fill="#FFA500" filter="url(#f1n8snf7oca3o3)" height="39.9404" rx="12.5" ry="12.5" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="65" x="125" y="20"/><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="14" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" textLength="45" x="135" y="46.8643">Ubuntu</text><rect fill="#90EE90" filter="url(#f1n8snf7oca3o3)" height="39.9404" rx="12.5" ry="12.5" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="83" x="240" y="20"/><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="14" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" textLength="63" x="250" y="46.8643">Linux Mint</text><path d="M190,39.9702 L200,39.9702 C215,39.9702 215,39.9702 230,39.9702 L240,39.9702 " fill="none" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.0;"/><path d="M75,69.9404 L85,69.9404 C100,69.9404 100,39.9702 115,39.9702 L125,39.9702 " fill="none" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.0;"/><rect fill="#008000" filter="url(#f1n8snf7oca3o3)" height="39.9404" rx="12.5" ry="12.5" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="72" x="125" y="79.9404"/><text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="14" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" textLength="52" x="135" y="106.8047">Rasbian</text><path d="M75,69.9404 L85,69.9404 C100,69.9404 100,99.9106 115,99.9106 L125,99.9106 " fill="none" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.0;"/><!--MD5=[a83dff5f9fd7a46abce9d8ea448b7c30]
@startmindmap
skinparam backgroundColor #EEAADD

*[#FF0000] Debian
**[#Orange] Ubuntu
***[#LightGreen] Linux Mint
**[#Green] Rasbian

@endmindmap 
--></g></svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

this method may work. (PlantUML Web Server not work)

```
@startmindmap

skinparam backgroundColor transparent

sprite $my_right_arrow [16x16/16]  {
    FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
    FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
    FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
    FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
    FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
    FFFFFFFFFF0FFFFF
    FFFFFFFFFF00FFFF
    FF00000000000FFF
    FF000000000000FF
    FF00000000000FFF
    FFFFFFFFFF00FFFF
    FFFFFFFFFF0FFFFF
    FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
    FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
    FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
    FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
}

* layer 1
 * layer 2
  * obj
  * obj
  * <color:00ffff> <&folder> obj folder
 * layer 2
  * <color:00ffff> <&folder> obj folder
  * <back:00ffff> <&folder> obj folder
  ' backgroundColor not work!
  * <color:00ffff> <$my_right_arrow> <color:000000> <size:30> test
@endmindmap
```

[image]

reference: http://plantuml.com/en/sprite